# Как правильно реализовать switch?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть `listener` который возвращает мне элемент, если я указываю условие с помощью `if` то все работает, если в помощью `switch` то подчеркивает и показывает ошибку... Что я делаю не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот так я нахожу свой `View` элемент

```
dsbGender = (DiscreteSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.dsbGender);
```

Comment: Там он пишет требуется константа. Если DiscreteSeekBar - это class | interface, то у него не может быть констант в принципе. Switch работает с числами, строками, enum. case 1 | case "abc" | case MyEnum.ONE. Переменных никакого вида в case не должно быть

Answer (score 10, accepted):

сделайте

```
 switch (seekBar.getId()) {
   case R.id.dsbGender:
     ...
 }
```